# how to get posted file from html input file using behind code ASP.NET

Tags: file-upload

I'm using jquery to copy 1 row to create 1 row below. Control is dynamic.
I have 1 control to copy and paste from tableclone

```
<input type="button" value="Add Row" id="addrowbutton" class="Button" />
```

This is the main table :

```
<table id="registrationtable" class="Grid">
<tr class="Caption">
    <th scope="col">
        Registration Number 
    </th>
    <th scope="col">  Is Install 
    </th>
    <th scope="col"> Upload File 
    </th>
    <th scope="col"> Remove 
    </th>
</tr>
```

And I clone from here

```
<table id="tableclone" style="display: none;">
<tbody>
    <tr class="Row">
        <td style="white-space:nowrap;">
            <input id="RegistrasiNo" class="RegistrasiNoClass" type="text" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlIsInstall" runat="server" class="IsInstallclass">
                <asp:ListItem Value="Y" Text="Yes"></asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Value="N" Text="No"></asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div style="float: left">
                <input type="file" id="fileUpload" class="fileuploadclass" />
            </div>
            <div style="float: left">
                <input type="button" value="Upload File" id="UploadFileControll" class="UploadFileControllclass" runat="server" />

            </div> 
        </td>
        <td><a href="#" class="removeItem">Remove</a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

```
<asp:Button ID="SaveRegistrationID" runat="server" Text="SAVE" OnClick="SaveRegistrationID_Click" CssClass="Button" />
```

How to get posted file from fileupload dynamicly (more than 1 row) when i click button SAVE ?